# LOG file for a VBA userform event activity

Tags: vba, excel, logging

I am trying to get an MI LOG for the usability of my userform i have created for my team.

I currently reached at a stage where i can only keep a track log of when the workbook has been opened and by who. But i want to go a bit further and also LOG what activities are performed on the user form such as what the user is searching and the results it pulls out.

See code below that i have currently in place: THE BELOW CODE IS PLACED IN MY MODULE:

```
Sub LogInformation(LogMessage As String)

    Const LogFileName As String = "C:\TEXTFILE.LOG"
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    FileNum = FreeFile ' next file number

    Open LogFileName For Append As #FileNum ' creates the file if it doesn't exist
    Print #FileNum, LogMessage ' write information at the end of the text file
    Close #FileNum ' close the file
End Sub

Public Sub DisplayLastLogInformation()

    Const LogFileName As String = "C:\TEXTFILE.LOG"
    Dim FileNum As Integer, tLine As String
    FileNum = FreeFile ' next file number

    Open LogFileName For Input Access Read Shared As #f ' open the file for reading

    Do While Not EOF(FileNum)
        Line Input #FileNum, tLine ' read a line from the text file
    Loop ' until the last line is read

    Close #FileNum ' close the file

    MsgBox tLine, vbInformation, "Last log information:"
End Sub

Sub DeleteLogFile(FullFileName As String)
    On Error Resume Next ' ignore possible errors
    Kill FullFileName ' delete the file if it exists and it is possible
    On Error GoTo 0 ' break on errors
End Sub
```

AND THIS CODE BELOW IS PLACE ON "ThisWorkBook"

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    LogInformation ThisWorkbook.Name & " opened by " & _
                   Application.username & " " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm")
End Sub
```

THE RESULTS I GET FROM A TXT FILE BELOW:

```
> Number Checker.xlsm opened by #username :  2017-08-30 09:12
> Number Checker.xlsm opened by #username :  2017-09-02 09:19
> Number Checker.xlsm opened by #username :  2017-09-07 09:21
```

The userform itself is a simple search tool and pulls back results depending on the search, this is where I need help to track on what the user searched for and what results i.e txtbox1 feedback . Is this possible or I'm running on a dead end? :(

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Create a log in a hidden sheet to capture any changes using each control's Change, Update, Enter/Exit etc. events. You can then flush the log sheet to a text file when the workbook closes.

Comment: I wouldn't user `Application.UserName` as that can be changed by the user in the _General_ tab in _Excel Options_.  User `Environ("username")` as that returns the system user name - which may still not be correct (for ages mine was just "Admin" until a recent upgrade).

Comment: @KostasK. thank you for your suggestion do you have a sample i could work on ?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook thank you will keep that in mind :)

Comment: Presumably you have a `Submit` or an `OK` button the end user to submit there query? If so, in `OnClick` call, you can capture search criteria, then preform the search and capture search results. Once you have all this, log it in your log file and then display the results. Also consider having the log file in your network drive. If it's on local machine, you wouldn't always be able to get access to the log file. Lastly, I would have the logging functionality in a `Class Module`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to say thank you all for your advice & help on pointing me to the right direction, i think i have managed to solve it out now, all i needed to do was to put this code under the `click event` :

```
LogInformation ThisWorkbook.Name & " - " & " Closed by - " & _
Environ("username") & " - " & Application.username & " - " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm") & " - " & " Number Searched For - " & _
    Me.check_number.Value & " - " & Me.number_status.Value
```

[problem solved] next task now :p

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple utility that helps me with that. It is called VBA Telemetry.

It connects VBA and Microsoft Azure Cloud for REAL-TIME logging and tracking of Events & Errors from VBA with 1 line of VBA code.

So you can log and track your VBA projects (Excel workbooks, Access projects) wherever in the world they are. And you see what is going on in your Azure Portal Application Insights resource (this is a new product from Microsoft Azure).

For example, if you want to track an Event you can do this with this function:

```
TrackEvent "CommandButton1ClickEvent"
```

There is also one more function TrackMetric where we can send also some custom data. For example, we can send, how long did it take for a loop to complete on a user machine.

```
TrackMetric "Loop1Duration", 100
```

Or if you want to track Errors (or exceptions) here is a sample code line:

```
TrackError Err.Description, Err.Number, "CommandButton1_Click"
```

You need a free account on Microsoft Azure cloud and a free version of this utility.

Here is a video (45 seconds) where I'm showing how to log (track) Events:

[Link to 45 sec video Track Events](https://youtu.be/jIH_6IokelQ)

You can see the details on how to do this in this article, there is also a youtube video (detailed webinar) in this article:
[Link to the article](https://www.vbatelemetry.com/full-guide-setup-vba-telemetry-azure-application-insights-track-usage-excel-workbooks/)

P.S.

As I've said at the beginning this helps me in my project for logging and error tracking in VBA Projects (Excel, Access), this is why I've made this also available for others. If you don't mind that from time to time a msgbox pops up you can use the free version, if not a one-time payment of few dollars will help me to further develop this little utility.

Hope this helps,
Davor